# Is it possible to get the members with the same score in a sorted set [Redis]?

Tags: redis

I'm using sorted sets in the following way.

I have a normal set called 'available:numbers' which contains phone numbers. Now say a user signs up, so we have a user id called 'uid'. This new user is alloted a number from the 'available:numbers' set. I have a user hash where I could store this user->alloted_number mapping. The problem is how to store multiple numbers associated with the same user?

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a sorted set here? I could POP a number from 'available:numbers' and add it to a sorted set called 'used:numbers' with the score that is the 'uid' of the user. Since score does not need to be unique and all members are unique, this  seems a perfect fit. What I want to know is that is it possible to get all members of a sorted set given a score? This way I could yank out all numbers belonging to a particular 'uid' Or should I just forget about sorted set for this purpose

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest that you keep a set for each user instead? So:

```
available:numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4}

user:numbers:UID1 = {5, 6}
user:numbers:UID2 = {7}
```

It seems more manageable, to me. That being said, you can indeed get all members of a sorted set by score, see [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

```
zrangebyscore user:numbers UID UID
```

I suggest you read through the documentation on all available commands in redis, the documentation is really top notch - and you can try out (most) commands live - really awesome.